# How can i make multidimensional arrays arduino

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, arduino

how can i make a multidimensional array in the arduino.

I would like to have this.

Javascript

```
    var array = {
      name: "John",
      age: "51",
      children: [
        "Sara",
        "Daniel"
      ]
    };
```

or this.

JSON

```
    {
      "name": "John",
      "age": "51",
      "children": [
        "Sara",
        "Daniel"
      ]
    };
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
var array = {
  name: "John",
  age: "51",
  children: [
    "Sara",
    "Daniel"
  ]
};
```

Is not a multiminesional array this is an object.